# How can I implement a custom video player in Swift that supports picture-in-picture mode and background playback?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am building an iOS app that requires a custom video player with some advanced features. I want to implement a player that can play videos in picture-in-picture mode, even when the app is minimized, and also continue playing in the background when the user switches to another app or locks the screen.

I have tried using the AVPlayerViewController class, but it doesn't seem to support picture-in-picture mode or background playback. I also looked at some third-party video player libraries, but none of them seem to support these features either.

Can anyone suggest a way to implement a custom video player in Swift that supports picture-in-picture mode and background playback? Any code samples or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller) does exactly what you want. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/1615821-allowspictureinpictureplayback

Comment: All you have to do is Google and you’ll find apple’s sample. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_for_video_calls

Comment: They all support background playing. You just haven't enabled playback in background mode in capabilities.